# Swift - multiple UIPickerViews that depend on each other

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a set of three picker views whose data values are dependent on the previous view. So, for example, in the first picker view you'd pick from A, B, & C and depending on the choice, the second picker view would show X, Y, or Z data. Same goes for the third. If nothing is chosen in a previous view, the remaining views show a blank string. The user can access each picker independently (i.e. only one picker view is showing at a time) by clicking on one of three different text views.

Here's the relevant code that I have already made. It works, kinda, but there are a few bugs and I was wondering if someone could help me make it better. The picker views let the user choose between (A) the country he/she lives in, (B) the state, and (C) the city. All of these values are stored in 3 dictionaries:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    countryPickerView = UIPickerView()
    statePickerView = UIPickerView()
    cityPickerView = UIPickerView()

    countryPickerView.delegate = self
    statePickerView.delegate = self
    cityPickerView.delegate = self

    countryPickerView.dataSource = self
    statePickerView.dataSource = self
    cityPickerView.dataSource = self

    countryPickerView.tag = 0
    statePickerView.tag = 1
    cityPickerView.tag = 2

    countryTextField.inputView = countryPickerView
    stateTextField.inputView = statePickerView
    cityTextField.inputView = cityPickerView
}

// Declares the number of separate components (NOT entries) in all picker views
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
    return 1
}

// Declares the number of entries in each picker view
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return Locations.getAllCountries().count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        if chosenCountry != nil && chosenCountry != "" {
            return Locations.getAllStatesForCountry(chosenCountry!).count
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        if chosenState != nil && chosenState != "" {
            return Locations.getAllCitiesForState(chosenState!).count
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    return 1
}

// Declares the text in each entry in each picker view
// Will be a blank string if the previous picker hasn't been selected yet
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return Locations.getAllCountries()[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        if chosenCountry != nil && chosenCountry != "" {
            return Locations.getAllStatesForCountry(chosenCountry!)[row]
        }
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        if chosenState != nil && chosenState != "" {
            return Locations.getAllCitiesForState(chosenState!)[row]
        }
    }

    return ""
}

// Sets the textfields to display the chosen text
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        countryTextField.text = Locations.getAllCountries()[row]
        chosenCountry = countryTextField.text!
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        if chosenCountry != nil && chosenCountry != "" {
            stateTextField.text = Locations.getAllCitiesForState(chosenState!)[row]
            chosenState = stateTextField.text!
        } else {
            stateTextField.text = ""
        }
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        if chosenState != nil && chosenState != "" {
            cityTextField.text = Locations.getAllCitiesForState(chosenState!)[row]
            chosenCity = cityTextField.text!
        } else {
            cityTextField.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

I am still very new to Swift and iOS, so please bear with me if this is a suboptimal solution. Has anybody done this before?

Comment: You could use the .hidden property, and when the user selects the first one, in didSelectRow update the data for next picker and then set .hidden for next picker to false.

Comment: Well the pickers get hidden automatically depending on what textfield you select. I think that's the purpose of `countryTextField.inputView = countryPickerView`. It replaces the regular keyboard with the picker view